# Referring one data frame to perform analysis on another data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I have one data frame, lets call it titles:

```
titles <- data.frame(V1=c("A", "B", "A", "B", "A", "A"))
```

I have another data frame called, stuff:

```
stuff <- data.frame(V1=c(1,2,3,4,5,6),
                    V2=c(10,20,30,40,50,60),
                    V3=c(1,3,5,7,9,11),
                    V4=c(2,4,6,8,10,12),
                    V5=c(9,8,7,6,5,4))
```

I would like to iterate through, so that in each column, I multiply all the rows that correspond with A and multiply all values in the rows that correspond to B

so basically...

for V1 in "stuff", I would multiply (1*3*5*6) because they correspond to A

for V1 in "stuff", I would multiply (2*4) because they correspond to B

I want to do this for EVERY column in Stuff in an apply statement and output the results. Help?

Comment: Are you aware that `titles` has six columns and `stuff` only has 5 columns?  I was wondering why my output differed from everyone else's and I believe recycling is the reason.

Answer (score 4):

Do it all in one go:

```
sapply(split(stuff, titles$V1), sapply, prod)
#        A   B
#V1     90   8
#V2 900000 800
#V3    495  21
#V4   1440  32
#V5   1260  48
```

Or even:

```
by(stuff, titles$V1, sapply, prod)
#titles$V1: A
#    V1     V2     V3     V4     V5 
#    90 900000    495   1440   1260 
#---------------------------------------
#titles$V1: B
# V1  V2  V3  V4  V5 
#  8 800  21  32  48
```

Answer (score 3):

For the "A" rows we could use

```
sapply(1:ncol(stuff), function(x) prod(stuff[titles$V1=="A",x]))
#[1]     90 900000    495   1440   1260
```

and, accordingly, for the "B" rows

```
sapply(1:ncol(stuff), function(x) prod(stuff[titles$V1=="B",x]))
#[1]   8 800  21  32  48
```

Answer (score 2):

An option using `data.table`.  We convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(stuff)`), grouped by the 'V1' column in 'titles', we loop (`lapply(..`) over the Subset of Data.table (`.SD`) and do the multiplication (`prod`).

```
library(data.table)
setDT(stuff)[, lapply(.SD, prod), by = .(titles[['V1']])]
#   titles V1     V2  V3   V4   V5
#1:      A 90 900000 495 1440 1260
#2:      B  8    800  21   32   48
```

Or a similar option using `dplyr` with `summarise_each`

```
library(dplyr)
stuff %>% 
      group_by(title=titles[['V1']])  %>%
      summarise_each(funs(prod))
#   title    V1     V2    V3    V4    V5
#   (fctr) (dbl)  (dbl) (dbl) (dbl) (dbl)
#1      A    90 900000   495  1440  1260
#2      B     8    800    21    32    48
```